# Gdal_merge doesn't work

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-merge

I have gdal installed and (I though) working fine. I use a lot rasterio and sometimes gdal directly, but today I wanted to do a mosaic and I wanted to try gdal_merge.py, but when I try to launch the tool I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\gdal_merge.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==2.1.1', 'gdal_merge.py')
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\pyqgis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'GDAL==2.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I don't know what happens here. I try to run directly the gdal command line and I get one message saying I don't have osgeo installed (I actually have it). So I am pretty lost here. I have been reading a lot of post about gdal installation but I do the same I always see, and the proof is that I can work with gdal (from python or the cmd), but I don't realize where is my mistake.

Comment: what does gdalinfo --version say?

Comment: Hi iant, "gdal 2.1.0 released 2016/04/25"

Comment: Remove currect 2.1.0 version then install the 2.1.1

Comment: The Python you are using thinks it is looking for 2.1.1

Comment: I don't know if that is the problem. I have just seen this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182243/gdal-merge-not-working-in-gdal-201-windows-install?rq=1 and the solution of type all the path is working now for me. So I guess it must be any other thing with the system paths

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have 2.1.1 installed in your Anaconda environment but an older 2.1 installed somewhere else (but present in the PATH).

Comment: Same issue here.  If you are calling through the command line you NEED to call ```python gdal_calc.py``` as opposed to just ```gdal_calc.py```.  In my case, I'm using Conda and I need to specify the path/to/gdal_<calc or merge>.py so I do: >>>```%CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\gdal_calc.py -A raster_to_update.tif --outfile fixed_raster.tif --calc="-9999*(A<-9999) + A*(A>=-9999)" --NoDataValue=-9999```  And that works.  As an example.  Here I needed uniform NoData vals.  Just to demonstrate the protocol of ```python``` + optional(if Conda) ```path/to/gdal_<merge or calc>.py```